# how to handle prediction with boolean output

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, prediction, preprocessor

there I'm doing a machine learning project. I'm trying to build a model for a dataset that outputs boolean. it's my first-time handline boolean output and I don't know what should I do to handle it

hers my screenshot of the dataset:
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHc78.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Another way is to manually convert the boolean labels to integers using a single loop and then use it for training.

Comment: i need that boolean response as it is